# https://docs.google.com/feeds/<user-id>/private/changes API is returning 404 errors

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

The API endpoint described here seems to not be working:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_changes_for_a_user

It seems that this API endpoint is returning 404 errors. This works when user-id is default, but not otherwise.

Comment: Kartik, I'm looking at it. Just because this is a deprecated API, I cant give you an ETA now.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Documents List API v3 either by appending a `v=3` as a query param/value

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/changes?v=3
```

or adding `GData-version: 3.0` to your headers.

Comment: Thanks Burcu though we are already using Gdata-version: 3.0.

Is this related to domain permissions?

The exact same call works for userid = default with both v=3 and Gdata-version: 3.0 ; both fail for a user other than default unless I am a domain administrator.

Working case:

    https://docs.google.com/feeds/<user in my domain I am an administrator of>/private/changes?alt=json&prettyprint=true&v=3 

Failure case ( returns 404 ):

    https://docs.google.com/feeds/<user in my domain I am not an administrator of>/private/changes?alt=json&prettyprint=true&v=3

Answer (score -2):

Don't use the deprecated Docs API. Drive API has a similar method to list changes. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. We're aware of the Drive API can't switch to it just yet.